# How to determine the wavefront

Tags: waves, huygens-principle

In case of symmetry around a point we can consider a sphere on whose surface points the waves are equidistant. But how to determine the wavefront around a linear source or a cylinder or triangle or of these or of an complex figure. Should I get the symmetry around every every point and integrate that? How to do it? And is there any alternative process to find it? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an alternate process: According to Huygens Principle the *wavefront* at time $t$ would be the envelope (or tangent surface) of all the Huygens wavelets originating from each point on the surface of the 'complex figure'.  The radius of the wavelets would be $ct$.

For an approximate graphical solution, you can draw a figure and work out the  results for the '*wavefront*' by drawing circles of radius ct centered at closely spaced points on the 'complex figure' and then draw their tangent surface.

Note that the complete '*wavefield*' is more involved.  The '*wavefront*' is the furthest extent of the wave, which is governed by causality.  The '*wavefield*'  includes what follows after the '*wavefront*'.

Google Huygens Principle to get images and further explanation. The images illustrate use of Huygens Principle.

Re. your "Should I get the symmetry around every every point and integrate that? How to do it?":  To solve for the *wavefield* of a geometrically complex source using math would involve numerically solving Kirchoff's or Poisson's formula--you can Google that too.